# How to add golden tone to sparkles

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, blend-modes

I have a layered file that consists of a colored background and sparkles over it. There are multiple sparkle layers of different sizes and intensities. The purpose of this file is to generate production images with various kinds of sparkles. I achieve it by tuning background color and sparkle layer opacity. Here's the simplified cropped example:

[image]

All layers are of Normal Blending mode, with the exception of the SPARKLES group, which is Color Dodge. And the resulting image is:

[image]

As you see, the sparkles have the same hue as the background. But the problem is, for some cases, I need to add a golden tone to the sparkles, so their color would look like (sparkles' form doesn't matter in this example, pay attention to color only):

[image]

And I don't know how to do it. I don't prefer duplicating sparkles in yellow, because there are too many layers to duplicate then, and I like the sparkles' appearance in Color Dodge mode - it keeps the original background hue, but just lacks a gold-tone there. Is there a way to add a golden effect in a single place? So it can be easily tuned. I tried to implement it with an adjustment layer, etc. - no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better control with the color I would recommend that you didn't use blend modes to achieve this, but instead used a *Solid Color* layer with a *Layer Mask*.

It should be pretty easy to convert what you have now:

- Place a black layer below your "Sparkles" layer. It should now look something like this:
  [image]
- *Select > All*.
- *Edit > Copy Merged*.
- Delete or turn off the black layer and the "Sparkles" group.
- In the bottom of the *Layers* panel, click the *Create new fill or adjustment layer* and select *Solid Color*.
- Choose a color (you can edit it later) and click *OK*.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click the *Layer mask thumbnail* on the solid color layer to enter the mask.
- *Edit > Paste* in the merged image of the sparkles. It's important that the black background is actually completely black in the darkest point. If it isn't you can use *Levels* ore some other adjustment to achieve it.
- *Select > Deselect*.
- Click the thumbnail of the solid color layer to exit the mask.

Now you can choose whatever color you like for the sparkles by double-clicking the solid color thumbnail. You can also click the the mask and edit it like any other grayscale image at any time.

[image]

Comment: I like this method, although it forces me to create an additional golden sparkle layer. I would add an edit that we may still get use of Blend Modes. I followed your steps and then tried to choose Darken mode and what a beautiful glints I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAHTL.png. Scaled to 400%. A gold-tone is added and the original blue hue preserved – that's important. Would it be convenient for you to include this info and embed this (or your) image, @Wolff? I have no copyrights here, so it's fine. I could delete the comment then. Then your answer would be fulfilled. Is that possible?

Comment: @HoRn, I can't reproduce your result. Don't fully understand what you do. Not sure I follow the part about an *additional* layer either. If you use this method from the start you wouldn't need the layers you have to begin with.

Comment: ... but yes, once you have a solid color layer (or ordinary layer) with a mask, you have just isolated color from transparency and can use whatever additional blend modes, effects etc. you want.

Comment: _Additional_ layer - ah, there are many layers with Blend modes to remake and I've got too far with them... So, while they remain, the new golden layer counts as additional.

Comment: I also played with hue to make tone vary a bit from sparkle to sparkle https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU6P2.png. Noise mask

Comment: @HoRn, seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I would...

- copy the composite image.
- Create a `Photo Filter` adjustment layer
- Paste the composite into the Photo Filter **mask**
- Adjust **Levels** on the mask to boost contrast
- Choose the Photo Filter color... and play with the density...

[image]

Kind of the same as Wolff's, but the photo filter slider offers a tad more subtle control.

Comment: We agree on one thing: use a mask.

Comment: Good that this method preserves the original blue hue. But with the photo filter, I notice that bright parts are gold, yet separate pixels stay not far from grey: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCSvk.jpg. Could anything be improved here? _Density_ or _Preserve Luminosity_ do not help here...

Comment: @HoRn You can try adjusting the Blend Mode for the Photo Filter Layer. That's about as much as you can do.